# Nginx "auth_request" like option for rate limiting

Tags: nginx

In Nginx I want to send a pre-request to another endpoint which checks for rate limiting violations. Basically exactly what `auth_request` does, but where auth_request only accepts authentication status codes (200, 401, 403), I want it to only allow rate limiting codes (200 or 429).

Is there a more general version of `auth_request` which could be used for this?

For now we're using `auth_request`, but the downside is it turns 429 status codes into 500s.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your current config, might be able to provide a workaround

Comment: @TarunLalwani my current config isn't really relevant. It's just 1 command "auth_request" that I'm entirely looking to replace with a more suitable option.

Comment: So if in same setup instead of 500 you can throw 429 it works for you as solution?

Comment: @TarunLalwani no. As I say in the post, auth_request turn anything that isn't 200, 401, 403 into 500. I want to be able to have a preflight request, but still return 429

Comment: That is what I am asking that the 500 returns can be easily turned into a 429. Does that work for you?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I don't understand your question. If you have a solution that can return 429 please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below config works for me and returns a 429 instead of 500

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {

   server {
      listen 80;

      location /api {
         auth_request /rate_limit;
         error_page 500 = @rate_limit_error;
         echo "You were allowed to access the API";
      }

      location @rate_limit_error {
          return 429 "Limit has been exceeded\n";
      }

      location = /rate_limit {
         internal;
         return 400 "Access is not allowed";
      }
   }
}
```

The test shows the correct response

```
$ curl -v localhost/api?count=2
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api?count=2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 429
< Server: openresty/1.11.2.2
< Date: Sat, 30 Sep 2017 18:50:56 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 24
< Connection: close
<
Limit has been exceeded
* Closing connection 0
```

If you don't want to return a message or something else. You can also use `error_page 500 = 429;`

Comment: Thanks! Does this also replace legitimate 500s from /api with 429s?

Comment: If you are using `proxy_pass` then it would still go as 500, because `proxy_pass` responses are passed as is. See this https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors